# How to use loop for in a formula in crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I have a table in the details section with 3 columns (ID_Player, Name Player, medal) the medal column take gold, silver or bronze. and in the header page section i have  3 images for each type of medal i need to display the images according to the medal value displayed in the details section??

I try:
in the supression option of the image 1 (gold):

```
numbervar i ;
for i:=1 to count({table.medal}) do
(
if ({table.medal} = "gold") then false else true
)
```

the same code for the 2 others images but always it read only the first record !!

Comment: what are your medal values to manipulate the images? or at any time there is only onve value in medal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the existence of a medal in separate formula that will be evaluated for all the records and pass the result as a global variable to suppress formula:
**formula hasMedal:**

```
Global NumberVar num_var;
If {table.medal} = "gold" Then
num_var := 1
```

**formula for suppress:**

```
EvaluateAfter({@hasMedal});
Global NumberVar num_var;
num_var = 0;
```

In your current for-loop the `NumberVar i` goes through all the values but `{table.medal}` is pointing at the first row the whole time.

Comment: thanks for your response but when i tried , all the images are displayed !!

Comment: So if you put formula `hasMedal` and `{table.medal}` to the details section do you still get to see values `1` and `gold` on at least one row?

Comment: I'll rephrase the question: if there is just one row with the gold medal the image will show, that was the premise of the question, right? Does the medal show even if there's zero rows with gold medals?

Comment: yes although i have zero rows gold medals the gold image appears :/

Comment: If you drag `hasMedal` to details does it print as `0`? You can try to change the last line of suppress formula to `num_var <> 1;`

Comment: Did you try to put `hasMedal` in the details section? What does it show?

Comment: please see what i shared in the last solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can not iterate for loop to display images bcoz it it refer to the current row..
you have to use nested if...else..to display image...

```
 if ({table.medal} = "gold") then 
     false 
else if ({table.medal} = "silver ") then
     false
else if ({table.medal} = "bronze") then    
     false   
else
     true
```

Comment: it always check the first record not all the record !!

Answer (score 0):

i try to put @hasmedal in the details section when gold value exist hasmedal take 1 else it take 0 . same thing for the other value (silver and bronze)         i have now 2 lines: the first line contain gold and the second contain silver .. the hasmedalGold appears 1 in the first line and 0 in the second line . and the hasmedalSilver appears 0 in the first line and 1 in the second... and hasmedalBronze appears 0 in the 2 lines in the supress formula i put this code :

```
    EvaluateAfter({@hasmedalGold});
Global NumberVar num_var;
num_var <> 0;
if ({@hasmedalGold} =1)
then false else true   

                                                                                              but the problem persist it display only the gold medal which is in the first line record :(
```